# python method taking information outside class

Tags: python, python-3.x

--EDIT-- Added my Employee class

Do methods only process information (attributes) from the class? Can method be used to process information from outside? 
How can I "promote" Sarah? So I have to create sarah employee instance but how do I make a manager to promote her?

```
class Employee:
    """Base infromation about any emploee"""

    def __init__(self, name, last_name, birthdate, email, phone, 
                    social_sec_no, credit_card, level):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.birthdate = birthdate
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.social_sec_no = social_sec_no
        self.credit_card = credit_card
        self.level = level #level 1-3 for laborer, 4- administration, 5 - plant manager

class PlantManager(Employee):
    """Plant manager:
        - Approves budget
        - Promotes
        - Gives order to hire - fire person
    """

    def __init__(self, name, last_name, birthdate, email, phone,
                    social_sec_no, credit_card, level):
        super().__init__(name, last_name, birthdate, email, phone,
                    social_sec_no, credit_card, level)


    def promotion(self, employee_lvl):
        if employee_lvl == 3: 
            return
        else:
            employee_lvl = employee_lvl + 1

manager = PlantManager('John', 'Stockton', '1989-05-15', 'taas@yahoo.com', '+17068645474',
                '5847-487-0', '222 484 999', 5)

sarah = 1

print(manager.promotion(sarah)) #returns None
```

Comment: Sarah sounds like the name of an Employee, not an integer.

Comment: Note, your `promotion` method doesn't do anything. It merely increments a local variable and returns `None`. Likely, `employee_lvl` should be an instance variable

Comment: You need to define a method `promotion` that takes an instance of `Employee` as an argument and returns a *new* instance of `Employee`, identical to the input except its `level` attribute is one higher than the input. (Or, `promotion` can simply mutate its argument, changing the level in-place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to promote an employee, you need to specify which one by providing it as argument.

```
class PlantManager(Employee):

    ...

    def promotion(self, employee):
        if employee.level >= 3: 
            raise ValueError('not allowed to promote') # better to raise than silently fail
        else:
            employee.level += 1
```

Then you can promote them.

```
sarah = Employee('Sarah', 'Connor', '1965-11-13', 'judgment@day.com', '123', '456', '789', 1)

manager.promote(sarah) # after all she went through

sarah.level # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an object called Sarah, like:

```
Sarah = Employee('sarah', 'name', '1989-05-15', 'taas@yahoo.com', '+17068645474',
            '5847-487-0', '222 484 999', 5)
```

Then you can call the promotion method to increase level:

```
Sarah.level = Manager.promote(Sarah.level)
```

The promote method for the `PlantManager` should also be edited so it returns the final value.

Edited with the new information.

Comment: yes, but note. `promotion` doesn't do anything. It merely increments a local variable then returns `None`

Comment: Oh yes that is right. I am not quite sure what the expected outcome should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your function promote doesn't return the value in the else part